# Playframework 2.3 test is not working

Tags: junit, playframework-2.3

I have migrated from play 2.2.1 to play 2.3.0 successfuly. My applications are working fine. But i am not able to run any test cases.When i run play test it returns result in command prompt like [info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1.. I am not able to see the UI in http://localhost:9000/@tests. I am only able to know the status like how may test cases passed and how many failed.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with http://localhost:9000/@tests? Isn't it a Play 1 thing?

Comment: I had something similar if I had errors during application startup (database, dependencies etc.). After fixing them, it worked again.